# Putting csv into list, accessing empty spaces in the last column gives a Index Out of Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The list is a 2D list from a CSV imported using the following:

```
filedata = open('file.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(filedata, delimiter=',')
data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)
```

Here is an example of the spreadsheet

```
 |  0      1           2       
 |-------|--------|--------------|
0|   4   |   5    | home/user/a  |
1|   3   |   6    | home/user/b  |
2|       |        | home/user/b  |
3|   7   |   34   |              |
```

and in CSV format

```
4,5,home/user/a
3,6,home/user/b
,,home/user/b
7,34
```

The issue happens if I attempt to get a value in data that is blank in the CSV but only in the last row. So something like `data[3][2]` will give me an out of bounds error but if I call something like `data[2][0]` it works fine and just gives me blank back which is what i want.

Im thinking that it's not making the list at that row long enough, but I don't  know how to make sure it is long enough

Im able to do a workaround to get all the information by checking the list length and if its less than the length of the complete lists, then it checks that value, but I feel that there is a much better way to do it then checking the lengths.

Comment: this is an issue with the actual csv file. Since the last row only contains two columns, the third one can't be reached and that why you're getting the index out of range error. Are you using a self-made .csv file, or something saved by for example excel?

Comment: Yeah I understand that that's the issue. And no Its not a self made one, its something that gets spit out of another program. And I combed through it and did not see any CSV options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, though it may only work in my case, I'm only looking for `home/user/a`, `home/user/b` or `/home/user/c`. You can use `data[-1]` and check the rightmost element in the array and can check to see what it is using that.